# Getting Environment must inherit from the gym.Env when it already does in Stable Baselines3

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have a script where I try to use `stable_baselines3.__version__='2.0.0a5'` methods over a custom Gym environment. The thing is that, even if my environment does inherit from the gym.Env class, I get the error `AssertionError: Your environment must inherit from the gym.Env class cf https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/core.py`

This is how my environment is instantiated:

```
import gym
class v1(gym.Env):
     """
    GYM functions
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # My implementation of the rest of the class here
```

And this is how I try to use it before it fails

```
gym_env = v1()
print("Check env: ")
check_env(gym_env)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Changelog](https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/misc/changelog.html#deprecations), it is stated that Stable Baselines 2.0.0a8 (at the time of writing)

> switched to Gymnasium as primary backend, Gym 0.21 and 0.26 are still supported via the `shimmy` package

I would consider using `Gymnasium` when using Stable Baselines 3 version > 2.0.0, or switch to an older version of Stable Baselines 3 (<2.0.0) to use the old `Gym`, or you could use the `shimmy` package as suggested if you want to look into that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! What you say makes sense. the thing is that I have tried to downgrade stable baselines to version  1.7.0, but for some reason I get an error: metadata-generation-failed. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: `pip install 'stable-baselines3==1.7.0' --force-reinstall`. This ensures to install the version 1.7.0 and `--force-reinstall` makes sure that the current version gets overwritten with the version you are trying to install.

Comment: I finally managed to uninstall the dependencies I had before and install the latest Stable Baselines3 in both environment, but your answer did work. Thank you!